# Drop default constraint which has an illegal name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, drop, default-constraint

I have several default constraints which now have illegal names due to a name-normalization script error (apparently `sp_rename` does a poor job of validating the `newname` parameter).

Some columns have actual default names in the format

```
[[DF_SomeTable_SomeColumn]]
```

or

```
[dbo.[DF_SomeOtherDefault]]
```

Neither `sp_rename` nor `Alter Table Drop Constraint` can remove them as they are reported as syntax errors.

How can I get rid of them, or rename them?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is probably to have SQL give you the correctly escaped constraint names using the `quotename` function. You can query the catalog views to generate the drop statements for you based on the table names. As an example:

```
-- this weirdness will create a default constraint called [[my weird default]]
create table t(i int constraint [[[my weird default]]]]] default (1))

-- find all the constraints with square bracket literals on the tables I care about
select  concat('alter table [', t.name, '] drop constraint ', quotename(c.name))
from    sys.tables                  t
join    sys.default_constraints c   on  c.parent_object_id = t.object_id
where   t.name = 't'
and     c.name like '%[[]%'


-- returns: alter table [t] drop constraint [[[my weird default]]]]]
```

Obviously, add the appropriate filtering to your query.

Comment: Those are system tables, not DMVs (dynamic management views).

Comment: @SMor Actually they're neither. They're catalog views. Fixed.

Comment: Good advice on using `quotename`. I'd apply it consistently though (ie in your script, also use it for the table name).